# Need to POST and close window when user clicks submit button

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

Right now I have the following:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Save' ,{:onClick => "window.close()"} %>
```

This works well for closing the window.  Unfortunately, it closes the window before the form POSTs to the server.

The window was created using a link in the homepage:

```
function amenitiesPopup(){
  window.open("/amenities", "Swag", "status,width=600,height=800,resizable,scrollbars=yes","POS"); 
}
```

Without the `:onClick => "window.close()"` the form POSTs as expected.  Just need to close it afterwards.

Thanks

Edit:  My solution was to have the controller return a string literal:

```
if (params[:search])
    ...
    render :text => '<body onload="window.close()"></body>'
end
```

This will skip any layout/view items and just render an empty body that auto-closes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return

`<body onload="window.close()">`

from the server, that way your POST is sure to go through before the window closes. So instead of closing from the submitting document, you close in the document received as reply by the server. Also, if you want to close the window afterwards, you might consider posting to an iframe instead depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter wants to explain what is bad about my answer so we can all learn from it? Thanks.

Comment: maybe because you missed the parens? still this is a viable solution if you have control of the destination page

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso Thanks very much! Indeed a fail of mine ;) Also, it's the only (besides using a different syntax like with script tags) simple solution I know of - if you don't have control of the destination, even a JS event listener won't always work due to same-origin policy and other things browsers get more paranoid about on nearly a daily base.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  What I ended up doing is just rending a literal string :)  I included the details in the OP

Comment: Just a little sidenote: you don't need the closing </body> tag there - while it's syntactically more correct, browsers (at least all the ones I know) don't have a problem with it missing (as well as a missing <html> or <head> tag). But that's only if you want to save the last few bytes (which is probably not an issue for you)

Answer (score 1):

```
function onSubmit(){
    $.ajax({
        //POST info and URL etc goes here
    }).done(function(){
        window.close();
    });
}
```

You need to specify all arguments required by the jquery ajax api (url, data, etc).

if you submit without ajax you'll go to the page you submitted to and will no longer have control of your window, unless you control the destination page, in which case you should add the window.close to the script of your destination page:

```
<script>
    window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: closing the window directly after submit is a bad idea, as that could - depending on browser etc - cancel the request.

Comment: true, since ajax is asynchronous. it should go at the end of the callback. Changed to include skeleton for an ajax call that will wait for the request to complete before closing

Comment: That should work now - only, you're missing a ')' at the end, and should also add that what you wrote is pseudocode/ which library it's supposed to use (can't remember one using "done", afaik most of them use "success", but I'd very much like to learn something new ;) )

Comment: done is called after the operation completes (i.e. regardless of success/failure). Thanks for the pointers though, I'll update accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, what I did was make the destination page a close event.  It loads quickly enough that it looks pretty good